# Playing YouTube audio stream in Third Party App

Tags: youtube-api

I'm developing an application in which I would like to play YouTube audio stream (without video). Does it violate any term of service of YouTube?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the YouTube API terms of service:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

The answer to your question is in section II, parts 8 and 9, stating it is prohibited to:

```
separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;
```

So it's a no-go, unfortunately.